# jstl core taglib is not working, spring framework web

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm beginning with jsp and spring framework in web. I have a controller, a model, and a view. I get some data from database in the controller and I have been trying to load it into the view, but when I try to show that data with the core tag lib it doesn't show anything. I have been looking for a solution, but I can't find anything, could you guys help me please?

This is my model:

```java
package com.valdezbaluarte.models;

import com.valdezbaluarte.dao.Dao;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;


public class Product extends Dao{

   private double price;
   private String description;
   private String name;

   public Product(){
       super();
       this.setTable("products");
   }

  public List get(){
      List productos = this.getTmp().queryForList("select * from products");
      return productos;
  }

  // getters and setters follow
}
```

My controller:

```java
package com.valdezbaluarte.controllers;

import com.valdezbaluarte.models.Product;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private Product producto;

    public HomeController(){
        this.producto = new Product();
    }

    @RequestMapping("home.htm")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        List datos = this.producto.get();
        //I know the query get results because I print them with this instruction:
        this.printlist(datos);  
        mav.addObject("datos",datos);
        mav.setViewName("home");
        return mav;
    }

     public void printlist(List l){
        for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("\n"+l.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

And finally the view:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head> 
        <body>
            <h1>Aca el home hommies</h1>
            <h2><c:out value="${productos}"/> </h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <th>Columna 1</th>
                <th>Columna 2</th>
                <th>Columna 3</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${datos}" var="dato">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${dato.description}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you add your dependencies?

Comment: Sorry, i'm using the netbeans IDE, when I created the project i just checked the spring mvc option , and thats all what I did, i don't know where is the dependencies file located, I was following a youtube tutorial and I did exactly the same as the video, the guy in the video never mentioned something about dependencies.